# how to map attribute content in saml2 sso connection

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, keycloak, saml-2.0

I have a sso connection from a Azure idp to Keycloack sp.
I can choose where to make it, but i need to make a mapping the content of an attribute of the SAML2 assertion.

I have a "user.depeartment" on microsoft Azure stack, that i want that the content should be  "mapped" like:

```
Department1=Team1 
Department2=Team1 
Department3=Team1 
Department4=Team2 
Department5=Team2 ....
```

This mapping should be static.
I have checkd both side but on keycloak i cannot really find where i can do this, on Microsoft Azure i spot "Regex-based claims transformation" but is not clear to me after appling some search function like:

```
\bDepartment[^N\s]*(?:\d)\b
```

for check the string "Department N" where N is a natural number > 0. So after i cannot under stand How to describe the substitution criteria in in a way like :

> Department1 > Team1 Department2 > Team1 Department3 > Team1
> Department4 > Team2 Department5 > Team2

or something like this that is making the mapping possible.